# Get ruby gem version without installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If I have a local gem (gemfile.gem) how can I get the name and version information from code or the command line without installing the gem.

Reason: I'm installing a user gem to validate it and want to uninstall it to clean up. User gem is not something I control so I can't depend on naming conventions.

CLI Solution:

```
gem spec gemfile.gem name
gem spec gemfile.gem version
```

Ruby Solution:

```
name = Psych.safe_load(`gem spec gemfile.gem name`).to_s
version = Psych.safe_load(`gem spec gemfile.gem version`, permitted_classes: [Gem::Version]).to_s
# Now you can uninstall the gem with
Gem::Uninstaller.new(name, {:version => version, :force => true}).uninstall
```

Comment: The version might not be frozen in the gemfile (usually is not), do you expect to get it from the Gemfile.lock or available versions that could be installed according to that gemfile or something else?

Comment: I added additional info to the question. I need the gem version not Gemfile versions.

Comment: @Jason Your question is written in a really confusing way... The title says "from gemfile", then you mention "gemfile.gem" (??!!!), then you say "nothing to do with Gemfile". If your question has got nothign to do with Gemfiles, then don't mention "gemfile" in the title and first sentence of the question!

Comment: Apologize for the bad wording. A gem file and a Gemfile are obviously two different things and I guess I missed the space. Should've just said 'local gem'. I updated the question again for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see locked version in `Gemfile.lock`

```
cat Gemfile.lock | grep gem-name
```

Other option, but need `bundle install` first

```
bundle exec gem dependency | grep gem-name
```

Update:

If you need to check local gem version, for example `some-gem.gem`, you can use [such command](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-specification) to parse all information from binary

```
gem specification some-gem.gem
```

or just

```
gem spec some-gem.gem
```

You can also look it with Ruby format

```
gem spec some-gem.gem --ruby
```

Of course you can use `grep` to filter lines with `version` word

But it's better to pass it as argument like this

```
gem spec some-gem.gem version
```

Comment: Thanks @mechnicov this got me on the right track. I was able to use Psych to load the yaml and get the values I want.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous. If you mean "How can I read in the gem name and version from the gemspec?" then you can use the output of [Gem::Specification#load](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-c-load). For example, assuming you have a gem with a standard layout and `foo_bar.gemspec` in the root of your gem's project directory, you can use Git to find the top-level of your project and read in the gemspec:

```bash
$ cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) 
$ ruby -e 'puts Gem::Specification.load "#{File.basename Dir.pwd}.gemspec"'
#<Gem::Specification name=foo_bar version=0.1.0>
```

You can then parse the output with sed, awk, or cut.

Comment: I have a fully compiled gem. I didn't expect to have to untar it and then look for the gemspec but perhaps that's the only way?

Answer (score 0):

A `Gemfile` does not (necessarily) specify an exact version of a dependency. It might specify nothing (i.e. "any version is fine"), or `~> 1.0` (i.e. `>= 1.0` and `< 2.0`), or whatever. Also, dependency constraints might further restrict the valid range of versions.

I'm *assuming* that this isn't what you meant by your question. Instead, you'd like to know what *exact versions* of dependencies will be installed by running `bundle install`, **given a `Gemfile.lock`**.

One way to achieve this reliably (i.e. rather than using `grep` and eyeballing which line(s) are most relevant) is by *parsing the `Gemfile.lock`*:

```
require 'bundler'

lockfile = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.read_file('Gemfile.lock'))

puts lockfile.specs.find { |spec| spec.name == 'the-gem-you-want-to-check' }.version
```

Comment: I need the gem version not Gemfile version